# Make values the index and replace values with 1 if present in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
      Snoopy    Mickey     Minnie     Garfield      SnowWhite
0     John      Mike       Steve      Joe           Jack
1     Mike      Jack       April      Joy           John
2     Steve     Joe        Jack       Mike          Jake
3                          Joy
```

I want to convert all unique values across all columns into the index, and make the values 1 and 0, like this:

```
      Snoopy    Mickey     Minnie     Garfield      SnowWhite
John  1         0          0          0             1
Mike  1         1          0          1             0
Steve 1         0          1          0             0
Jack  0         1          1          0             1
Joe   0         1          0          1             0
April 0         0          1          0             0
Joy   0         0          1          1             0
Jake  0         0          0          0             1
```

I also have a list of all the unique values already:

```
clients = ['John','Mike','Steve','Jack','Joe','April','Joy','Jake']
```

Is this possible to do? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use `melt` and `crosstap`

```
s=df.melt()
s=pd.crosstab(s.variable,s.value)
Out[8]: 
value      April  Jack  Jake  Joe  John  Joy  Mike  Steve
variable                                                 
Garfield       0     0     0    1     0    1     1      0
Mickey         0     1     0    1     0    0     1      0
Minnie         1     1     0    0     0    0     0      1
Snoopy         0     0     0    0     1    0     1      1
SnowWhite      0     1     1    0     1    0     0      0
```